# How to insert og:video meta tags in drupal

Tags: drupal, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I've tried a couple of things to achieve the above.
I installed the integrated meta tag module which gave me the following results

```
<meta name="og:description" content="In this episode, XYZ reporter No Butt Nagir goes undercover to investigate the poor working conditions of house helps, Obama issues a travel alert to Kenya due to the possibility of a terror attack, and Ruto performs Maino’s All the Above!" />
<meta name="og:image" content="http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/4RTFJosA-320.jpg" />
<meta name="og:site_name" content="www/buni.tv" />
<meta name="og:title" content="The XYZ Show Season 6: Episode 5" />
<meta name="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta name="og:url" content="http://buni.asilialtd.com/video/xyz-show-season-6-episode-5" />
<meta name="og:video" content="https://content.bitsontherun.com/players/4RTFJosA-DawDpxmw.swf" />
<meta name="og:video:height" content="315" />
<meta name="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta name="og:video:width" content="480" />
```

However i'd like to change `<meta name=` to `<meta property=`

Thanks